# How to create folder shortcuts in file manager?

Tags: file-manager, thunar, bookmarks

[image]

I'm using Thunar. What i want is remove `Networks` since i don't use it, and add `Lello` below `videos`. I know if you right click on any folder like `videos` you can remove the shortcut, I don't know how to add shortcuts.

Comment: can we also automate this via xfconf-query or something? I would like to use command-line only.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Under Thunar file manager, you can add to the shortcut pane by dragging items there as [shown in the Thunar documentation](http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/the-file-manager-window).

Answer (score 15):

An alternative to drag and drop is the [Send To](http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/send-to) menu:

1. Right-click on the folder you want to add as bookmark
2. <kbd>Send to</kbd> → <kbd>Side Pane (Create Shortcut)</kbd>

Drag and drop didn’t work for me. According to [a post in the thread *Thunar bookmarks are broken. Salix64 Xfce 14.1*](https://forum.salixos.org/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=5269&start=10#p33808), the reason is the missing file `~/.gtk-bookmarks`. After using the Send To method once, the file gets created (you could create it manually, too). When this file exists, drag and drop works again.

As the bookmarks get saved in this `.gtk-bookmarks` file (might depend on your version, though), another alternative is editing it directly:

```
file:///home/unor/photos/new
file:///home/unor/Downloads
```

Comment: In my Ubuntu 20.04 I found the file `~/.gtk-bookmarks` was moved to `.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks`

Answer (score 5):

AHEM....
you probably have TREE VIEW enabled.
In tree view, shortcuts do not appear in the side pane, even if they exist.
(View menu > Side Pane > Shortcuts / Tree).
The tree function presumably can't deal with shortcuts.

Comment: Consequently, drag and drop doesn't work in Tree View.

Comment: Ctrl +E / Ctrl +B to do the quick switch, which is nice

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

1. right-click on the folder you want
2. in the contextual menu, put the pointer on "Send to"
3. and then click "Side-pane (Create shortcut)"

edit: sorry, I didn't see [the above answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/341914/318461). I only saw the complaint about drag & drop not working.